# Ternary tree vs trie with map as transition table for Aho-Corasick FSA

Tags: algorithm, trie, finite-automata, ternary-search-tree, aho-corasick

What is the difference between FSA using ternary tree and a trie with transition tables implemented as search trees (e.g. std::map)? It seems like both have O(log k) complexity for reading one symbol and O(S) memory complexity, where k is alphabet size and S is sum of lengths of all accepted input strings.

And wouldn't the best choice be to use sorted vector of (symbol, state) transition pairs along with binary search, if we don't need the automata to change in runtime?

Answer (score 3):

There is no real difference between a Ternary Search Tree (TST) and a Trie implemented with a binary search tree at each node. Indeed, you could regard the latter as an (inefficient) implementation of the former; the advantage of TSTs is that they can easily be optimized, and the space overhead is reasonable.

The classic Trie uses direct lookup at decision nodes with a vector of transitions indexed by symbol. This is `O(1)` time, but the space requirement is substantial. Nonetheless, there are ways of optimizing the storage. Also, hybrid solutions exist, where the Trie structure is only used for the wide decision nodes at the top of the tree; once the number of candidates is reduced to something small, a fast scan or hash table can be used to find the appropriate candidate.

Using a sorted vector of (symbol, state) transitions in a naive fashion requires `O(log T)` time for each transition, where `T` is the total number of transitions; essentially the total size of all the input strings. The total time for a given target will be `|target|*log(T)`.

By contrast, TSTs require no more than `O(log S)` time for each transition, where `S` is the size of the alphabet; that's a much smaller number than `T`. Moreover, the total number of lookups over the entire target string is limited by the number of input strings, so the sum over the entire lookup is rather less than `|target|*log(S)`.

Comment: Why are you suggesting that vector<Symbol, State> has a size of O(T)? I don't see any difference from using binary search tree here. If automata is deterministic, we can have no more transitions from each state than the size of alphabet.

Comment: @lizarisk: perhaps I misunderstood your suggestion. Aren't you suggesting one single array for the entire tree? Or are you suggesting a vector for every state? If the latter, it's morally equivalent to a binary search tree so I don't really see the point of the question. (In practice, for example, my TST implementation does use a vector rather than individual nodes, but I regard that as an implementation detail.)

Comment: I'm suggesting a vector for each state. It's equivalent to binary search tree in terms of search complexity, but I think it's more efficient because of the dense representation in memory.

Comment: What I want to know is whether sorted vector for transitions tables is more effective than ternary tree. Perhaps it's hard to tell without practical tests, but I've heard that ternary trees are used widely, and vector approach seems more effective to me as long as we don't need dynamic structure, so the question is why are TST used at all?

Comment: If your alphabet has 26 letters, a vector takes about the same space as a ternary tree, assuming moderate filling of the transition table. If your alphabet is unicode, your vectors will be huge, while ternary trees are likely to remain small. Regardless, the only way to get a proper answer is to write both versions of the program and compare them on actual data to see which version is better in your particular situation.

Comment: @lizarisk, TSTs are used precisely because we usually do need dynamic updating. Also, they're simple. But I reiterate that storing a binary tree with implicit links as an array (See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_tree#Arrays) is just an implementation detail. It's worth doing if your datastructure is not going to change.

Comment: @user448810: See above comment; you can store a BST (or ternary tree) with implicit links in an array, in which case it takes less space than the alphabet vector. Anyway, the alphabet of valid symbol characters is rarely less than 36 and generally at least 63 `(a-zA-Z0-9_)`. However, I agree that compression of vectors is practical.

Answer (score 0):

Given how Aho-Corasick is illustrated,

[image: Aho-Corasick]

Here is my Node:

```
public class AhoCorasickNode
{

    // This part works as a Trie

    public char literal; // c

    public String stack; // abc

    public AhoCorasickNode previous; // { ab }

    public AhoCorasickNode[] next; // { abca }, { abcb }, { abcc }, ..

    //-----------------------------

    // This part is used when solving

    boolean inDictionary;

    public AhoCorasickNode suffix;

    public AhoCorasickNode dictionarySuffix;

}
```

Source:

- [Wikipedia: Aho-Corasick](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aho%E2%80%93Corasick_string_matching_algorithm)